# Is there a way to make Azure WebJobs ServiceBus out parameter optional?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am building a console application that will be run as a continuous Azure WebJob. I am using the Azure WebJobs SDK via the Nuget Package Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.ServiceBus v0.3.1-beta (prerelease). I have static method that triggers on an Azure ServiceBus queue. I do some processing and then want to have the **option** to send a response via the output parameter to another queue. The method signature looks like this:

```
public static void TriggerOnQueue(
     [ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName)] BrokeredMessage receivedMessage,
     [ServiceBus(QueueResponseName)] out BrokeredMessage responseMessage)
{
      ...
}
```

My initial thought was to set the responseMessage to null. However, when I do this an error appears in the console window. It doesn't stop execution (so it technically does what I want it to do), but I would rather not push something throwing errors to production. Is there any non-hackish way to set a value in the response message that will not throw an error, but will not submit the message to the response queue?

If not, is there another pattern I am missing that I could use? I would prefer to use the pipeline feature of the WebJobs SDK as opposed to creating the output queue manually. I could probably submit the requests that need a response on to a separate queue and have 2 separate triggers, but with the small amount I am having this do I would rather keep it simple and together.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern of specifying null for an out parameter works for Azure Queues but it throws an exception for Service Bus Queues. This looks like  bug in the SDK. I will open a bug for us to fix it. Thank you for reporting this issue

Comment: Thank you! I'll be looking forward to the fix :)

Comment: I wonder if this was fixed. All of this automatic declarative infrastructure makes me nervous. You have to search for documentation for how it's supposed to work (if you can find any docs). Then when you think you understand how it should work, you start developing and something like this happens, where it doesn't behave as it should, and you end up writing the code that the infrastructure promised you wouldn't have to write in the first place! If you're lucky enough to get it working, you have to pray that a bug isn't introduced when they update the SDK!

Comment: This is now fixed.